# mysql cursor update next rows then upcoming rows have old value or new value

Tags: mysql

I have a cursor to update country_id column of one table.

Here is the my code .

```
 DECLARE cdrs_id INT;

 DECLARE cdrs_callenum VARCHAR(30);

 DECLARE country_id INT;

DECLARE cdrs_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT `id`,`callednum`, from `cdrs` where `country_id` = 0;

OPEN cdrs_cursor;
    cdrs_loop : LOOP
        FETCH cdrs_cursor into cdrs_id,cdrs_callenum;
        IF FINISHED=1  THEN 
            LEAVE cdrs_cursor;
        END IF;
        select id,countrycode into country_id,countrycode from countrycode where countrycode in (substring(cdrs_callenum,1,4),substring(cdrs_callenum,1,3),substring(cdrs_callenum,1,2),substring(cdrs_callenum,1,1)) order by length(countrycode) desc limit 1;
        IF(country_id > 0 ) THEN
            UPDATE `cdrs` set `country_id` = country_id where callednum like concat(countrycode,"%");
        END IF;
    END LOOP cdrs_loop;
CLOSE cdrs_cursor;
```

Here is the table cdrs

```
ID | CALLEDNUM | COUNTRYID
1  | 91929394  | 0
2  | 9199222   | 0
3  | 91939395  | 88 
4  | 919596    | 0
```

If i am going to execute query below on 1st row

```
update cdrs set country_id = 88 where callednum like(91%);
```

So, When cursor move to 2nd row it have country_id is 88 or 0.
Here after execute above query 2nd row have country_id is 88

Please, Let me know if not possible to make this kind of cursor as i have make code but didn't execute it yet.

Comment: @Akina  : Thanks for reply but i just want to know one simple thing, If we update next rows from cursor then when cursor will at  that row that time,It have new row data or old row data. For example, When cursor on 1st row that time i am updating 2nd and  4th row column country_id value from 0 to 88. So when cursor will check 2nd row that time it have country_id is 0 or 88. Please, Let me know if its not clear for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we update next rows from cursor then when cursor will at that row that time,It have new row data or old row data.

You will get non-updated value.

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8befad4c2e509776200ecebb8d1b07c0).

```sql
-- Prepare test data
create table test (id int, val1 int, val2 int);
insert into test (id, val1, val2) values (1,11,111), (2,22,222), (3,33,333);
select * from test;
```

Output:

```
id  val1    val2
1   11      111
2   22      222
3   33      333
```

```sql
-- create test procedure
create procedure test_cursor ()
begin
declare done int default false;
declare v_id int;
declare v_val2 int;
declare cur cursor for select id, val2 from test order by id;
declare continue handler for not found set done = true;
open cur;
loop1: loop
  fetch cur into v_id, v_val2;
  if done then 
    leave loop1; 
  end if;
  -- try to update the next row
  update test set test.val2 = v_val2 where test.id = v_id + 1;
end loop loop1;
close cur;
end
```

```sql
-- execute procedure and check the result
call test_cursor();
select * from test;
```

Output:

```
id  val1    val2
1   11      111
2   22      111
3   33      222
```

---

As you can see the 3rd row is updated with the value `222` which is initial for 2nd row. But at the moment when 2nd row was fetched it was already updated using value `111` taken from 1st row in previous `LOOP` step.

---

Read [Restrictions on Server-Side Cursors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursor-restrictions.html) also:

> In MySQL, a server-side cursor is materialized into an internal temporary table.